# nginx how to create server block for sub domain?

Tags: nginx

I have a domain `http://blabla.com` which points to an ip address `103.35.123.4.12`. I then have a sub domain `http://mew.blabla.com` which points to the same ip address. Using nginx how can I differentiate between the two domain names? I currently have the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blabla.com;

    location ^~ / {

    }
}

server {
    listen 80
    server_name mew.blabla.com;

    location ^~ /mew/ {

    }
}
```

Currently both blabla.com and mew.blabla.com redirect to the root directory, how can I create a server block for the sub domain?

EDIT: Currently **mew.blabla.com** is not being recognised as the subdomain, is it a problem with both domains sharing the same IP?

Comment: No, it is not a problem with both domains sharing the same IP. You don't have any `root` configuration (which tells nginx from where to serve files) and `location` doesn't do what I think you think it does (for example, that last one only matches requests for `mew.blabla.com/mew/`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blabla.com;
    root /var/www/blabla.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mew.blabla.com;
    root /var/www/mew.blabla.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

So, then content for mew.blabla.com will be served from the path /var/www/mew.blabla.com, while content for blabla.com will be served from the path /var/www/blabla.com.